# How can I get grep to skip searching directories?

Tags: grep

When I do a `grep foo *` I get a number of warnings like this:

```
grep: dir1: Is a directory
grep: dir2: Is a directory
grep: dir3: Is a directory
grep: dir4: Is a directory
grep: dir5: Is a directory
```

I would rather just see the results rather than these warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep foo * --directories=skip` will skip grepping directories like regular files.

As per the man page:

> ```
>  -d action, --directories=action
>          Specify the demanded action for directories.  It is `read' by default, which means that the directories
>          are read in the same manner as normal files.  Other possible values are `skip' to silently ignore the
>          directories, and `recurse' to read them recursively, which has the same effect as the -R and -r option.
> ```

Also, `grep foo * -s` will do something similarly satisfying.

> ```
>  -s, --no-messages
>          Silent mode.  Nonexistent and unreadable files are ignored (i.e. their error messages are suppressed).
> ```